# Consequences of NOT unregistering a dll when deleting during uninstall?

Tags: .net, dll, com

What's the worst thing that can happen?  Let's assume an app is deleted from the hard disk, but the DLLs don't get unregistered, and then a newer version of the app is installed.

Could the registration for the old DLLs end up pointing to the new ones, but contain incorrect type data?

If the new DLLs are put somewhere different, could the registration for the old ones cause a call to the (registered) new ones to fail?

Comment: "I'm planning to do things the wrong way, when I know what the right way to do things is. What's likely to happen?"

Comment: *it depends*.  If the install detects the old registration and doesn't update it, then yes, it will point to the old dlls.  If it simply overwrites the registration, then it will point to the new dlls.  But, what does "registration" mean to you?

Comment: @Damien Well go on then smart arse, tell me :-)

Comment: @PeterRitchie (sorry mistaken identity!) Registration, to me, means that native DLLs are registered with regsvr32 and .NET with regasm.

Comment: `regasm /codebase`, even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For COM registered DLLs I definitely recommend unregistering before copying new files.  The un-registration process (when done with an installer) will detect in-use dlls and warn you that you need to reboot.  Plus, this also means that the DLLs can't be loaded (once unregistered) *while* you copying new files or registering new files.

Comment: These are good points.  Assuming the user doesn't try to do that, though, will the old registrations be left 'dangling' and interfere with the new ones?

Comment: With COM components, you're never really sure when/how they'll get used.  It may not be a direct action by the user.